# User fill textbox but keep other textboxes empty

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am creating a form with multiple textboxes the will be used for increasing or reducing recipes. I would like to have the unused textboxes to remain empty and not display anything such a "0". I am new to VB and need some help. Here is my code and it will display "0" in the textboxes for the receiving value.

```
If TextBox12.Text = "" Then
        TextBox30.Text = Val(TextBox11.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox13.Text = "" Then
        TextBox29.Text = Val(TextBox12.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox14.Text = "" Then
        TextBox28.Text = Val(TextBox13.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox15.Text = "" Then
        TextBox27.Text = Val(TextBox14.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox16.Text = "" Then
        TextBox26.Text = Val(TextBox15.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox17.Text = "" Then
        TextBox25.Text = Val(TextBox16.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox18.Text = "" Then
        TextBox24.Text = Val(TextBox17.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox19.Text = "" Then
        TextBox23.Text = Val(TextBox18.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox20.Text = "" Then
        TextBox22.Text = Val(TextBox19.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox20.Text <> "" Then
        TextBox21.Text = Val(TextBox20.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If
```

Please any assistance would be great

Comment: You should employ meaningful names for your controls.

Comment: Do you mean like changing "textbox12" to say Item 1?

Comment: According to the image, something like: `txtOriginalAmt1` and `txtConvertedAmt1`. Or just `txtOrgAmt1` and `txtConAmt1`. This way you know which of which.

Answer (score 0):

You just add another if then statement :-

```
If TextBox12.Text = "" Then
    TextBox30.Text = Val(TextBox11.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
         if val(textbox30.text)=0 then textbox30.text=""
End If
```

Comment: Please check below added screenshot and complete code.

Comment: I added the statement and it didn't change anything

Comment: You must enter the statement on all of the textboxes where text="" and you doing a calculation. Also very important the if then statement's(code) must also be in the form load event.

Also button 3 click code must be in form load event

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screenshot and the complete code so you can see what I am having an issue with. I want to have the text boxes on the right side to remain empty after the calculation is done.

Screenshot: https://photos.app.goo.gl/AunvLrmhPtdJf67V9

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox40.Text = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox39.Text = TextBox2.Text
    TextBox38.Text = TextBox3.Text
    TextBox37.Text = TextBox4.Text
    TextBox36.Text = TextBox5.Text
    TextBox35.Text = TextBox6.Text
    TextBox34.Text = TextBox7.Text
    TextBox33.Text = TextBox8.Text
    TextBox32.Text = TextBox9.Text
    TextBox31.Text = TextBox10.Text
    TextBox41.Text = ComboBox1.Text
    TextBox42.Text = ComboBox2.Text
    TextBox43.Text = ComboBox3.Text
    TextBox44.Text = ComboBox4.Text
    TextBox45.Text = ComboBox5.Text
    TextBox46.Text = ComboBox6.Text
    TextBox47.Text = ComboBox7.Text
    TextBox48.Text = ComboBox8.Text
    TextBox49.Text = ComboBox9.Text
    TextBox50.Text = ComboBox10.Text



    If TextBox12.Text = "" Then
        TextBox30.Text = Val(TextBox11.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox13.Text = "" Then
        TextBox29.Text = Val(TextBox12.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox14.Text = "" Then
        TextBox28.Text = Val(TextBox13.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox15.Text = "" Then
        TextBox27.Text = Val(TextBox14.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox16.Text = "" Then
        TextBox26.Text = Val(TextBox15.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox17.Text = "" Then
        TextBox25.Text = Val(TextBox16.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox18.Text = "" Then
        TextBox24.Text = Val(TextBox17.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox19.Text = "" Then
        TextBox23.Text = Val(TextBox18.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox20.Text = "" Then
        TextBox22.Text = Val(TextBox19.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If

    If TextBox20.Text <> "" Then
        TextBox21.Text = Val(TextBox20.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    End If


    'TextBox29.Text = Val(TextBox12.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    'TextBox28.Text = Val(TextBox13.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    'TextBox27.Text = Val(TextBox14.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    'TextBox26.Text = Val(TextBox15.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    'TextBox25.Text = Val(TextBox16.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    'TextBox24.Text = Val(TextBox17.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    'TextBox23.Text = Val(TextBox18.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    'TextBox22.Text = Val(TextBox19.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
    'TextBox21.Text = Val(TextBox20.Text) / Val(TextBox51.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox40.Text = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox39.Text = TextBox2.Text
    TextBox38.Text = TextBox3.Text
    TextBox37.Text = TextBox4.Text
    TextBox36.Text = TextBox5.Text
    TextBox35.Text = TextBox6.Text
    TextBox34.Text = TextBox7.Text
    TextBox33.Text = TextBox8.Text
    TextBox32.Text = TextBox9.Text
    TextBox31.Text = TextBox10.Text
    TextBox41.Text = ComboBox1.Text
    TextBox42.Text = ComboBox2.Text
    TextBox43.Text = ComboBox3.Text
    TextBox44.Text = ComboBox4.Text
    TextBox45.Text = ComboBox5.Text
    TextBox46.Text = ComboBox6.Text
    TextBox47.Text = ComboBox7.Text
    TextBox48.Text = ComboBox8.Text
    TextBox49.Text = ComboBox9.Text
    TextBox50.Text = ComboBox10.Text

    TextBox30.Text = Val(TextBox11.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
    TextBox29.Text = Val(TextBox12.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
    TextBox28.Text = Val(TextBox13.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
    TextBox27.Text = Val(TextBox14.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
    TextBox26.Text = Val(TextBox15.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
    TextBox25.Text = Val(TextBox16.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
    TextBox24.Text = Val(TextBox17.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
    TextBox23.Text = Val(TextBox18.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
    TextBox22.Text = Val(TextBox19.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
    TextBox21.Text = Val(TextBox20.Text) * Val(TextBox52.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim t As Control
    For Each t In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf t Is TextBox Then
            t.Text = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class